# Accessing limited data from solr

Tags: search, solr, memcached

I have huge amount of data to be searched. I want to search from solr, and solr only returns the ids of the searched records. 
Now i have a cache of all the records in solr (Memcache) and want to fetch whole data set from cache.

Is it good idea ? Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the problem is? Just define the 'fl' parameter to be the list of fields you want to return, in which case 'id'.

And if you never actually return the other fields, don't bother storing them, define them as index only. If you do have to store them but only want them very rarely, test using enableLazyFieldLoading setting in [solrconfig.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml)